# How to fix problem about installing the tensorflow in wsl2 (Python 3.8)?

Tags: tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-3.8

******Background:******
I use the jupyter notebook to learn the deep learning.
Here are the parameters for my computer:

```
The operation system: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)  
Python version: 3.8.2
```

****Problem:****
**I cannot install tensorflow.**

I follow the commend of website(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

```
 pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

It issues the problem:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

And I try to another way to install the tensorflow:

```
sudo pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

There is still a problem like this:

```
tensorflow_cpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I don't know how to fix the problem, please help me! Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/gpu-tensorflow-wsl)? Difference that you need just tensorflow. Try it with conda

Comment: @Alex K. Yes, I try to this but still exist the error. Maybe I drop down the Python version and try to download the tensorflow

Comment: Try upgrading the pip and python, and try again with `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` or try with `pip install tensorflow-directml`

Comment: At the time of this comment, Python 3.8 is not supported by tensorflow-directml. See https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml#system-requirements